# What would be the best way to combine rank responses for a parameter in survey?

Tags: survey, ranking

I have responses for a survey question where I asked the respondents to rank 5 options. For example:

response ID option 1    option 2    option 3    option 4    option 5
1   2   3   4   5   1
2   3   4   5   1   2
3   2   3   4   5   1
4   4   5   1   2   3

What is the best way to represent this in analysis? For example, if want to display results at option level?